# How to convert two same strings to the same unicode or code?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have a string coming from the LocaleSidKey by using the toLabel method. We are using language translations:

```
User currUser = [SELECT Id, toLabel(LocaleSidKey), Current_LOB__c FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];
```

Lets say, I am getting a value of the LocaleSidKey as "Français (France)"

I have another field called "language" on a custom object. It is a list of languages and its translated values.
When i try to compare the translated values of this custom field to the above 'Français (France)' from LocaleSidKey, I am getting the result as false (even though they spell exactly the same). When i check using "codePointAt" of the String class, i found that one of the characters had a different unicode.
Is it possible to convert both the strings to the same unicode format? how would we go about doing that

Comment: Are you able to copy and paste the exact strings into your post, or share the hex representations of the strings and their differing characters via `codePointAt()`? This sounds  like a difference in Unicode normalization.

Comment: Another way you can compare is to call `escapeUnicode()` on both characters and show the results.

Comment: @DavidReed I figured it out. the localsidKey values and the values provided to me for translations had different cases. Thank you for your reply